# what's the correct log-in response for twitter (for iPhone) with my custom APi

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am writing a custom API for twitter which will be used in Twitter for iPhone. what's the response my third-party API gives to twitter can make twitter think the user is logged in.

I know the twitter for iPhone auth step is using XAuth to /oauth/access_token, when it is set my API, I will gives the response 'oauth_token=191074378-1GWuHmFyyKQUKWV6sR6EEzSCdLGnhqyZFBqLagHp&oauth_token_secret=NpCkpRRC5hGEtikMLnQ2eEcEZ0SIVF5Hb2ZgIwmYgdA&user_id=191074378&screen_name=oauth_test_exec&x_auth_expires=0' directly to twitter for iPhone. but twitter tells me server intern error rather than a correct response. what is the incorrect part ?

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have revealed your OAuth tokens anyone can copy them and use them to violate the Twitter TOS. You should go to dev.twitter.com and reset your OAuth tokens immediately. This is why it is called and OAuth Secret.

Comment: screen_name=oauth_test_exec&x_auth_expires=0' It's OK, it's twitter official test account maybe .